# why java stream "reduce()" accumulates the same object

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-stream, reduce

```
        ComparisonResults comparisonResults = requestsList
                .parallelStream()
                .map(item -> getResponse(item))
                .map(item -> compareToBl(item))
                .reduce(new ComparisonResults(), (result1, result2) ->
                {
                    result1.addSingleResult(result2);
                    return result1;
                });
```

when

```
    private ComparisonResults compareToBl(CompleteRoutingResponseShort completeRoutingResponseShortFresh) {
...

        ComparisonResults comparisonResults = new ComparisonResults();
...
            return comparisonResults;
}
```

however when I debug:

```
 .reduce(new ComparisonResults(), (result1, result2) ->
                    {
                        result1.addSingleResult(result2);
                        return result1;
                    });
```

I see `result1` and `result2` are always the same object (object id in the 
IDEA)

`result1` equals `result2`

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: I want to accumulate the different objects into one object. Not the same one to itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addSingleResult` should return a new object as modified a copy of `this` so you should change your code to:

```
.reduce(new ComparisonResults(), (result1, result2) ->
                {
                    return result1.addSingleResult(result2);
                });
```

Otherwise, you are always returning the same instance (without modifications).

From [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#reduce):

> The reduce operation always returns a new value. However, the
>   accumulator function also returns a new value every time it processes
>   an element of a stream. Suppose that you want to reduce the elements
>   of a stream to a more complex object, such as a collection. This might
>   hinder the performance of your application. If your reduce operation
>   involves adding elements to a collection, then every time your
>   accumulator function processes an element, it creates a new collection
>   that includes the element, which is inefficient. It would be more
>   efficient for you to update an existing collection instead. You can do
>   this with the Stream.collect method, which the next section describes.

Comment: `addSingleResult()` returns void. I should change it to non-void?

Comment: @EladBenda Yes, you should return a new element with the aggregated information in order to use reduce. Check my answer edit.

Comment: @EladBenda In general, you have 2 ways of reducing a sequence: (A) Update the state of a single accumulation instance [Like what you initially tried to do]. (B) For each element of the initial sequence return a new accumulator instance.
To follow the (A) strategy you should use `collect` wereas `reduce` is good for (B).